# Can i put a newline in a resourcefile for Client Side Validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, newline

I have a form with a client side validationsummary.
View:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    ...
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Example)
    ...
}
```

I get the text of my errormessage out of a resourcefile, Resources\Resources.resx.
Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "err_Example", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
public string Example{ get; set; }
```

**Now i want the errormessage to contain a newline.**
But when I put \n or <br/> in the text in the resourcefile it does not convert to html..
How can i fix this?

Comment: is it escaping the html? actually writing the `<br />`?

Comment: @WorldsRound Yes , it writes the \n or \r\n in the html..
@Josiah Also yes, it is actualy writing the <br />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's HTML, I would have expected the white space to be collapsed, however, something like [this blog post](http://addinit.com/node/59) which shows you how to intercept the validation summary would work. Instead of wrapping the validation summary in a `<div>` element as the blog posts demonstrates you could use a `<pre>` element, or intercept the validation summary and replace `\n` with `<br \>`.

Comment: I was wrong this does work. I had to put the @Html.Validationsummary between a <pre> element + replace("\\n","\n"). Thank you very much!!

Comment: Just found out that the replace("\\n", "\n") is not necessary if you replace the \n in your resourcefile with a shift + enter... Thanks again.